# Got memory pressure notification (critical/non-critical) - iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, sdwebimage

Got memory pressure notification (critical/non-critical).

“n” numbers of images loading from API in tableview. But the app is crashing with above mentioned error after few seconds. 
The current code is,

```
[post_img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.jpg"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

I tried remove cache,

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i] fromDisk:YES withCompletion:nil];
```

Also, I tried to fetch images using dispatchqueue,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            post_img.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        });
    });
```

But still I getting the error.

Comment: I think you are testing on some old device. Get rid of that and test on newer one. Also store smaller size image  on your server.

Comment: three things will happen here 1. may be your image weight is high, 2. your app memory high 3. your device memory is low.